# Are there any other functions that have $\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}=0$?

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations

We've been doing partial differential equations this semester and solving the heat equation, which sometimes involves solving $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}=0$ which is satisfied when $u = Ax + B$

Is this the only function that has this property? I was just curious and had never questioned this before. Also in the same vein, are there any other functions that have $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}= \pm\lambda^2\cdot u$ apart from $A\cosh\lambda x+B\sinh\lambda x$ for positive and $A\cos\lambda x + B\sin\lambda x$ for negative, even though I see the motivation for these more clearly due to the use of the characteristic equation and the exponentials $e^{\lambda x}$

Comment: What is the domain of $u$?

Comment: @Chinny84 Ah yes thank you, and let's say the function is $u(x,t)$ so $0 \le x \le L$ and $t \in [0, \infty)$ Crostul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use partial derivatives, you implicitly say that this a function of several variables, i.e.: $u(x,y)$ for example.
Then, all solutions of the PDE :
$$\frac{\partial^2 u(x,y)}{\partial^2 x}=0$$
are :
$$u(x,y)=A(y)x+B(y)$$
where $A,B$ are any functions of $y$

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I forgot! So technically there are an infinite set of functions? And also are there any different *forms* i.e. not looking like a linear function?

Comment: Yes, the set of solutions depends on two arbitrary functions. This is the difference between the PDE and the ODE : the set of solutions of the ODE is based on two arbitrary constants. In the case of this PDE, The solutions are functions linear relatively to $x$, but not linear (and/ or linear) relatively to $y$.